# altium layers all black

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I have an Altium display on the PCB editor which shows all layers but the one selected as black. I have tried ctrl-s, the mask level and clear. Nothing seems to help. Any other suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Shift-S, not Ctrl-S, IIRC.

Comment: The Photon is right. It highlights the current layer and dims the others everytime you press Shift+S. So you can revert it to original by pressing. same combination.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "SHIFT-s" did work. I was using "ctrl-s".